# docker-compose service cannot access another service through its name

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am quite new to docker but after watching a few tutorials I gathered that if I wanted my services to have common code I had to use docker-compose.

This is my directory structure:

```
- project
   - docker-compose.yml
   - packages
       - common
          - src
             - eureka
                - eureka-helper.js
       - gateway
          - Dockerfile
          - src 
             - (some more directories and files)
          - server.js
       - users
          - Dockerfile
          - src 
             - app.js
             - (some more directories and files)
```

```
version: '3'

services:
    eureka:
        image: springcloud/eureka
        ports:
            - "8761:8761"
    gateway: 
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./packages/gateway/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        links:
            - eureka
    users: 
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./users/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "3004:3004"
        links:
            - mongo
            - eureka
    mongo:
        image: mongo
        volumes:
            -  C:\Users\myUser\docker\mongodb-data:/data/db
        ports: 
            - "27017:27017"
```

My server.js (inside gateway) and app.js (inside users) call a function inside eureka-helper that registers with Eureka.

```
eurekaHelper.registerWithEureka('gateway', eureka, port);
```

But it seems that server.js doesn't have a value for this eureka:

```
gateway_1  | /opt/app/gateway/server.js:27
gateway_1  | eurekaHelper.registerWithEureka('gateway', eureka, port);
gateway_1  |                                            ^
gateway_1  |
gateway_1  | ReferenceError: eureka is not defined
```

As per this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/, it doesn't seem that I really need the link in docker-compose:

> Links allow you to define extra aliases by which a service is reachable from another service. They are not required to enable services to communicate - by default, any service can reach any other service at that service’s name.

... but gateway is not able to reach eureka anyways.

Any idea if I'm missing something.

When I do inspect in gateway:

```
        "Networks": {
            "*project*_default": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "gateway",
                    "a358b371de9d"
                ],
                "NetworkID": "d986ee77bf6181e9dd59711650359dc49fd8ce3fc34c6772133a0049ab55bd3b",
                "EndpointID": "9633a7affe435793345342d4f6d00d5bef43d2267676448dfde0f97d75d5f7af",
                "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.19.0.3",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
```

When I do inspect in eureka:

```
        "Networks": {
            "*project*_default": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "eureka",
                    "17a218bf6e9e"
                ],
                "NetworkID": "d986ee77bf6181e9dd59711650359dc49fd8ce3fc34c6772133a0049ab55bd3b",
                "EndpointID": "43f4a9eb9efd4d30ad65d2c943065b8fb32ed50822bd553e07a2b0020c173fec",
                "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.19.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
```

Comment: try passing them as environment variable and use that environment variable in the code.

Comment: I've not used links before... Maybe try putting them in networks instead. Containers in the same network can reach each other by service name. By default all services are inside the `default` network, so all containers reach each other.

Comment: This does not look like a docker or docker compose problem, but rather a programming error in your code. I believe `ReferenceError: eureka is not defined` is telling you that you have not defined the variable `eureka`.

Comment: I added quotes around eureka when calling the function and now it works: eurekaHelper.registerWithEureka('users', 'eureka', port);